# Generic remapping of "import" statements

Tags: compilation, vim

I have `vim` setup to report `solc` errors while editing via [syntastic](https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic).

If I have the line:

```
import 'zeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/StandardToken.sol';
```

I receive the error:

```
Source "zeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/StandardToken.sol" not found: Unknown exception in read callback. [solidity/solc]
```

I get the analogous error at the command line using `solc`.

However `truffle compile --all` works just fine.

I have vim setup with:

```
let g:syntastic_solidity_checkers   = ['solc', 'solium']
```

How do I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice to be able to simply change the import path to:

```
../node_modules/zeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/StandardToken.sol
```

However, due to the solidity issue ["Add support to --allow-paths for relative paths #2928"](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/2928) you can't. :(

---

There is a work-around, and it's not very pretty.

Change the import statement to include the full absolute path eg:

```
import '/home/ravi/repo/ico/node_modules/zeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/StandardToken.sol';
```

And then add to the `vimrc` file:

```
let g:syntastic_solidity_solc_args = "--allow-path /"
```